# Why am I getting this error when I try to write the type definition of a local function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci, hugs

This my definition of the function any'

```
any' :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
any' f = foldl' step False
       where step :: Bool -> t -> Bool
             step b x | f x       = True
                      | otherwise = b
```

I get this error when loading in hugs:

```
ERROR "folds.hs":65 - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : step
*** Expected type : Bool -> a -> Bool
*** Inferred type : Bool -> _7 -> Bool
```

... and this in ghci:

```
folds.hs:65:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `t' with actual type `t1'
      `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for any' :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
          at folds.hs:62:9
      `t1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for step :: Bool -> t1 -> Bool at folds.hs:64:22
    In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
    In the expression: f x
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for `step':
      f x
```

When I remove the type definition of step It works fine, so my question is...
There is a way to correctly write that type definition or am I dealing with one of those situations where local functions can't be explicitly typed?

Comment: You need the scoped type variables extension, otherwise the compiler sees the second t as another new polymorphic type variable, rather than the same t as in the main type declaration.

Comment: btw, why foldl' and not foldr?

Comment: you're right Sassa NF, foldr is better since allows things like "any' even (repeat 2)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `t` in the signature

```
where step :: Bool -> t -> Bool
```

is not the same `t` as that occurring in the signature of `any'`. Instead, it is interpreted as a fresh type variable which is local to the `step` signature.

In other words, your code is actually equivalent to

```
any' :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
any' f = foldl' step False
   where step :: Bool -> a -> Bool          -- t renamed to a
         step b x | f x       = True
                  | otherwise = b
```

and the compiler then complains because `step` claims in its signature to be applicable to any type `a` while f requires a `t`.

A possible fix is removing the `step` signature. In this case the compiler will infer the right type on its own. This is not entirely pleasant from the programmer's point of view, since the compiler now will not check that the `step` signature really is the one which the programmer intended.

Another fix, as suggested in the comments, is to enable a Haskell extension which allows us to write our type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.List

any' :: forall t. (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
any' f = foldl' step False
       where step :: Bool -> t -> Bool
             step b x | f x       = True
                      | otherwise = b
```

Here the explicit quantifier `forall t` tells the compiler that the `t` occurring inside the definition of `any'` is really the same `t`, and not a fresh type variable.

Comment: thanks! great answer.
Do you know if there is any drawback on using that extension? I guess that there is, otherwise it would be enabled by default.

Comment: @matiascelasco no drawback, but for the fact that the compiler must support it. GHC does.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, the explcit `forall` is required, otherwise `t` will not be brought into scope in the `step` signature.

Comment: Apparently I don't understand how scoped type variables work at all... I thought it just meant that _all_ type variables stay in scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need the scoped type variables extension, otherwise the compiler sees the second `t` as another new polymorphic type variable, rather than the same `t` as in the main type declaration.

The clue that this is happening is in the message `Couldn't match expected type 't' with actual type 't1'`. Clearly ghci has renamed the second `t` `t1`, because it doesn't consider them the same.

You can use `ScopedTypeVariables` and an explicit `forall` to bring the `t` into scope for the inner function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

any' :: forall t.(t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
any' f = foldl' step False
       where step :: Bool -> t -> Bool
             step b x | f x       = True
                      | otherwise = b
```